# How to delete entire log from logstash index?

Tags: logstash

I'd like to remove entire log form logstash. 
I know how to remove some fields from each log or add, change fields but I'd like to remove entire log with some patterns, I just don't need to store them at elasticsearch database.
Condition works perfect for me and I am able to remove all fields except for fields with "@" sing

```
{
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-09-27T14:46:48.890Z"
}
```

I have an error after tried to remove those fields:

```
" {:timestamp=>"2016-09-27T15:05:56.451000+0000", :message=>"Pipeline main started"}
LogStash::Error: Unable to format in string "YYYY.MM.dd", @timestamp field not found "
```

Does anyone have idea how to delete that entire log?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the entire log, instead of removing all of the fields, use the [drop](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html) filter. It will drop every log that gets to it. :)

Comment: Ok how to do that :D